# Car no longer displays PRNDL and will not register its gear position

Tags: starting, transmission, nissan, gear-stick, pathfinder

Prior to this my car (a 2008 Nissan Pathfinder) would hard shift from 1st, 2nd & 3rd gears sometimes. Went to the store and after starting the car it reversed fine I put it into D and accelerated. Between gears 1 & 2 there was a soft shift or thud. It went but with no power and high rpm, eventually the car caught up to a normal speed.

Got it home and parked it but noticed it had no "P"on dash display . I reluctantly shut off the engine and tried to start it but noticed it didn't have the PRNDL indicator any longer on my dash and it did not start.

The shifter still goes through the shift sequence on the middle dash but car doesn't go into gear nor does it register any gear on my dash which may be why it won't start

Comment: We need to know, at a minimum, the year, make and model of the car.

Comment: Apologies so it's a 2008 Nissan Pathfinder

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It seems as though the transmission doesn't understand what gear it's in ... like it's between gears. If you take the selector lever down to where neutral should be (or anywhere beyond park) do the gears reappear on the dash? I'm *thinking* the transmission may not be going all the way into park or at least the computer isn't *seeing* it as going all the way into park. It might register neutral, though, which would allow you to start the vehicle (or should ... most cars will allow you to start in neutral).

Comment: This is what I.explained to wife... The computer still probably thinks it's in d hence no display on dash as well as not starting because the system hasnt distinguished if it is in d n or p. Which would allow my car to start so what do I do

Comment: Set your parking brake. With you foot on brake pedal, turn the key to the start position while moving the shift lever slowly all the way through and between gears. If at some point the starter engages, you need to have the linkage adjusted.

Comment: Ok I'll try. I tried putting the shifter in n to start still doesn't display prnd on dash neither will tranny shift. Into any gear or neither will the car start. The brake lights work so the brake censor is fine

Comment: Where's the linkage located is it easy to locate or fix

Comment: Doesn't sound like the problem is the linkage, but it is an easy place to start. With someone is in the car with car off, have them move the shift lever through the gears. You should see some corresponding movement somewhere on the transmission. That is where the shift cable meets the linkage. If you do see the cable moving the linkage, then the problem probably isn't the linkage because at some point the transmission would engage. Be sure to search for any bad electrical connections to the transmission and fluid levels, beyond this, you'll probably need a transmission shop.